# Passing matrix in recursive sudoku solver

Tags: python, function, recursion, matrix, sudoku

So I've written a brute force sudoku solver in C  a while ago. I thought it would be nice to have it in Python as well, so I kind of just translated the logic I had (a function for checking if a value can be legally placed at (x,y) and one that finds all the solutions recursively). Everything else (mostly i/o) I was able to replace with one-liners (hooray for Python).

Problem is, the code doesn't work. "sud" is a 9x9 matrix which (in the beginning) contains the unsolved sudoku. Unknown numbers are represented by a zero.

The program doesn't seem to change the values stored in "sud", so I'm guessing the problem lies in the scope in which my matrix is defined? In C I had defined "sud" as external, how do I go about doing that in Python? Or do I need to pass the matrix to my functions as an argument?

Sorry if my problem seems trivial, I'm pretty new to Python.

Below is the code I have so far:

```
N = 9
f = open('sudoku.txt', 'r')
tmp = f.read().splitlines()
sud = [[int(x) for x in tmp[i]] for i in range(N)]

def check(x, y, val):
    if val in [i for i in sud[y]]:                  ### check row x for val
       return 1
    if val in [sud[i][x] for i in range(N)]:        ### check column y for val
       return 1
    xbox = int(x/3) * 3
    ybox = int(y/3) * 3
    for i in range(xbox, xbox+3):
        for j in range(ybox, ybox+3):
            if val == sud[i][j]:                    ### check box for val
                return 1
    return 0

def solve(x = 0, y = 0):
    if x == N:
        y += 1
        x = 0
        if y == N:
            return 1
    if sud[y][x] > 0:
        return solve(x + 1, y)
    for i in range(1, N+1):
        if not check(x, y, i):
            sud[y][x] = i
            if solve(x + 1, y):
                print(sud)
    sud[y][x] = 0
    return 0
```

Comment: what is sud's type? how is it defined?

Comment: I added it to the description.

Comment: _"I'm guessing the problem lies in the scope in which my matrix is defined"_. I don't think that's likely. If `sud` is defined at the top of the file, then all functions in that file should be able to access and mutate `sud`.

Comment: Just for clarification, I tossed this at ideone (modifying it slightly) and the problem is that it fails to solve puzzles, correct? "doesn't work" adequately describes everything posted to this site.  (ideone: http://ideone.com/dhnRYs)

Comment: @Wug Yes, that's the problem. When I call `solve()` nothing happens and when I print out `sud` after the function call it's still exactly the same list as before. That's why I'm thinking the code fails to change the list like it's supposed to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for i in range(xbox, xbox+3):
    for j in range(ybox, ybox+3):
        if val == sud[i][j]:                    ### check box for val
            return 1
```

Looks like you mixed up your x and y indexing on the `if` line here; in the rest of your code, y comes first and x comes second.

```
for i in range(xbox, xbox+3):
    for j in range(ybox, ybox+3):
        if val == sud[j][i]:                    ### check box for val
            return 1
```

[Testing this](http://ideone.com/341ssC) against the sample grid that Wug kindly provided, produces output that seems to be correct.

Comment: Oh god did I really do that. I spent an embarrassing amount of time _not_ finding that. It works, thank you so much.